# How to get the uploaded file name with jquery-filedrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anyone familiar with [jquery-filedrop](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop). I want to get the file name with jquery-filedrop.

In filedrop how to get the uploaded file name? Because I want to display the name after file upload.

This is my template code

```
var template = '&lt;div class="preview"&gt;'+
  '&lt;span class="imageHolder"&gt;'+
  '&lt;img /&gt;'+
  '&lt;span class="uploaded"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;'+
  '&lt;/span&gt;'+
  '&lt;div class="progressHolder"&gt;'+
  '&lt;div class="progress"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;+
  '&lt;/div>'+
  '&lt;div class="name"&gt;'+file.name+'&lt;/div&gt;'+
  '&lt;/div&gt;';
```

I use file.name, but it does not work. The console shows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: file is not defined

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the part of code where do you initialize the filedrop?

Comment: i have solve it.this is my initialize the filedrop code uploadFinished:function(i,file,response){
   $.data(file).addClass('done');
   // response is the JSON object that post_file.php returns
   $.data(file).find('.name').text(file.name);
  }

Comment: Ok nice, could you post your answer so that everyone will know your solution to this issue.

Comment: i am sorry.my english is not very good.I do not know how to use english to express my solution.

Comment: in filedrop document find example code " uploadFinished: function(i, file, response, time) {
        // response is the data you got back from server in JSON format.
    }" in this function could get the file name with jquery-filedrop

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
files[0].filename
```

based on the number of files uploaded the index will change